# Python with subprocess

Tags: python, linux

I am trying to learn Python, using Python 2.6. This is my first script:

```
#!usr/bin/python
import subprocess

command = subprocess.Popen(['date'])
print command.communicate()
```

It works and prints the date, however it seems to print (None, None) as below:

```
[root@localhost ~]# python tester.py
Thu Apr 17 14:03:00 BST 2014
(None, None)
[root@localhost ~]#
```

How can I make it not print that, and just print the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default when you call `Popen`, the subprocess inherits Pythons standard streams (stdin, stdout and stderr). So, stdout will be the terminal, and date will echo straight to it. You can see this by comment out your print and noticing that the date still gets printed. To have the stdout echo into a Python string instead, pass the special value `subprocess.PIPE` to use as stdout:

```
command = subprocess.Popen(['date'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print command.communicate()
```

and you will get something like this:

```
('Thu Apr 17 23:11:16 EST 2014\n', None)
```

the remaining `None` is the stderr of the subprocess - you can also set it to PIPE, in which case it would be an empty string (unless `date` does print something to stderr). But to get just the stdout, you can use `command.communicate()[0]`.

---

Two side notes: first, it would be a good idea to upgrade your Python if you can. Most new programs should probably use Python 3, but if you must use Python 2, at least use 2.7 rather than 2.6. More importantly, it is a *really* bad idea to run things as root if you don't have to - and in this case, you really don't (and if you ever *do*, you should set up your program so it only uses root when it needs to).

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the subprocess up for communication:

```
>>> from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
>>> command = Popen(['date'], stdout=PIPE)
>>> command.communicate()
('do apr 17 15:06:16 CEST 2014\n', None)
```

The first part of the return value is `stdout`, the second is `stderr`.

Comment: however, how can I format it so it displays just the date command output and not \n or None at the end?

Comment: @user3227965 `communicate` returns a tuple `(stdout, stderr)`; you can get *just* the stdout by doing `command.communicate()[0]`. That will be a string, and when printed directly, the `'\n'` will be displayed a newline instead of escaped.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `date`, it just prints it's output to the terminal.  That's the first line of output you were seeing.  To not see the `(None, None)`, you can modify your code to not include the `print` statement.

```
#!usr/bin/python
import subprocess

command = subprocess.Popen(['date'])
command.communicate()
```

This will give you the output you want.  Possibly an easier method would be

```
#!usr/bin/python
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['date'])
```

If you want to collect the output yourself and possibly use it, you can use

```
#!usr/bin/python
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output(['date'])
print output
```

In general, you probably get away with using `subprocess.call` or `subprocess.check_output` instead of `subprocess.Popen`; `Popen` will work, but it is overkill in many situations.